# Derivation of pdf from cdf for integer part of exponential with rate $\lambda$

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

For a variable X with integer part [X], I have found the CDF of [X] to be 
$1-e^{- \lambda (x+1)}$, where X is an exponentially distributed function with rate $\lambda$.
How do I proceed from here to obtain the pmf of [X], $(e^{ \lambda } - 1)e^{- \lambda (x+1)}$? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[X]$ is now a discrete random variable, so you should go back to the discrete formulas.  Let $F(x) = P([X] \le x)$ be the cdf of $[X]$ and let $p(x) = P([X] = x)$ be the pmf. Then you have

$$p(x) = P([X] = x) = P([X] \le x) - P([X] \le x-1) = F(x) - F(x-1).$$

Note that you have to treat the case $p(0)$ separately because $F(-1) = P([X] \le -1)$ isn't given by the general formula you found, which only applies for nonnegative $x$.

Comment: Didn't you mix up $X$ and $[X]$? For example, $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$...

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you both; I have now solved for the pmf.

Comment: To the editors: You're correct that I intended $[X]$, not $X$, and a pmf, not a pdf.  Thanks for fixing.